# Connection Refused, how to solve?

Tags: java, linux, localhost

I've been working on a service with java tutorial, and was listening to it through localhost:8082. It was working just fine, but since I've turned off the computer it returns the error connection refused when I try to listen to it, and the only ports that present different responses are 8080 and 8081, which get the same error when I try to listen to the service through them.

Here's the code:

```
package io.vertx.book.message;

import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.rxjava.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.rxjava.core.eventbus.Message;
import rx.Single;

public class HelloConsumerMicroservice extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(
                req -> {
                    Single<JsonObject> obs1 = vertx.eventBus()
                        .<JsonObject>rxSend("hello", "Luke")
                        .map(Message::body);
                    Single<JsonObject> obs2 = vertx.eventBus()
                        .<JsonObject>rxSend("hello", "Leia")
                        .map(Message::body);

                    Single
                        .zip(obs1, obs2, (luke, leia) ->
                            new JsonObject()
                                .put("Luke", luke.getString("message")
                                    + " from " + luke.getString("served-by"))
                                .put("Leia", leia.getString("message")
                                    + " from " + leia.getString("served-by"))
                        )
                        .subscribe(
                            x -> req.response().end(x.encodePrettily()),
                            t -> req.response().setStatusCode(500).end(t.getMessage())
                        );
                })
            .listen(8082);
    }

}
```

That's the response I've got:
[image: error returned]

I don't know why it stopped working, but I've already browsed through a lot of answers and already tried cleaning my cache, but no improvements. Could anyone help?

I'm using Linux 18.04, Chrome/Firefox (both get connection refused).

Comment: Check netstat of the running process. If the port is open chech strace output with (e.g.) telnet/curl to get the error description. If this does not help check what error returns `accept` syscall  (if any) on thr server side.

Answer (score 1):

As your using Ubuntu it might be your firewall not allowing connections to that port.

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo ufw allow 8082
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Just tried it, returned rules updated but still got the same error message

Comment: It might be worth finding out if something is already using/blocking port 8082. alternatively you could make it listen on a different port?

Comment: That's the thing Damian, It refuses access in almost all of the ports, the only ones that present different outcomes are 8080 and 8081 which still doesn't connect, but return a different error.

Comment: And the other ports that you have tried using you have allowed through the firewall? Port 8080 and 8082 are fairly common ports and may be used by something else?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow after shytting everything down and restarting the machine, everything came back to normal, so... Don't know what happened, but it's all right now... It might've been used by something else. Thanks anyways for the help!